# Nest can't resolve dependencies of ThrottlerGuard

Tags: nestjs, peer-dependencies

I have 2 repos, one is my host repo, and one is where my throttler is present.
In the host repo I have my throttler as a dependency in my `package.json`.

I have 2 files in the throttler package:

`GqlThrottlerGuard:`

```js
@Injectable()
export class GqlThrottlerGuard extends ThrottlerGuard {
    getRequestResponse(context: ExecutionContext): { res: Response; req: Request } {
        if (context.getType<GqlContextType>() === 'graphql') {
            const gqlCtx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
            const ctx = gqlCtx.getContext();

            return { req: ctx.req, res: ctx.req.res };
        }

        const ctx = context.switchToHttp();
        return { req: ctx.getRequest(), res: ctx.getRequest() };
    }
}
```

`GraphqlThrottlerModule:`

```js
@Module({
    imports: [
        ThrottlerModule.forRootAsync({
            imports: [ConfigModule],
            inject: [ConfigService],
            useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => [
                {
                    ttl: +config.get('THROTTLE_TTL'),
                    limit: +config.get('THROTTLE_LIMIT'),
                },
            ],
        }),
    ],
    providers: [GqlThrottlerGuard],
    exports: [GqlThrottlerGuard],
})
export class GraphqlThrottlerModule {}
```

And my throttler `package.json:`

```
{
    "name": "my-own-throttler",
    "version": "1.0.0",
     ...
    "dependencies": {
        "@nestjs/config": "^3.1.1",
        "@nestjs/core": "^9.0.0",
        "@nestjs/graphql": "^11.0.6",
        "@nestjs/throttler": "^5.0.0",
        "rxjs": "^7.8.1"
    }
}
```

In my host repo I'm using my throttler like this:

`app.module:`

```js
@Module({
    imports: [
        ...
        GraphqlThrottlerModule,
    ],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: APP_GUARD,
            useClass: GqlThrottlerGuard,
        },
    ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

`package.json:`

```
{
    "name": "my-host",
    "version": "1.0.0",
     ...
    "dependencies": {
        "@nestjs/common": "^9.0.0",
        "@nestjs/core": "^9.0.0",
        "my-own-throttler": "1.0.0",
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
        "rxjs": "^7.2.0"
    }
}
```

When i'm running my app, it shows me this error:

```
 Nest can't resolve dependencies of the GqlThrottlerGuard (THROTTLER:MODULE_OPTIONS,
Symbol(ThrottlerStorage), ?).
 Please make sure that the argument Reflector at index [2] is 
available in the GraphqlThrottlerModule context.
```

When I put the same throttler code in the host repo, it works, but when I put it as a dependency in my `package.json` it does not work.

I suspected it might be a peer dependency issue, but when I tried to put the throttler as a peer dependency in the throttler `package.json` it still did not work.
I also tried to install `@nestjs/throttler@4.0.0` which uses nestjs 9, but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `my-own-throttler` package, when publishing the `@nestjs/` packages should be set to `peerDependencies`, except for maybe `@nestjs/throttler` if you aren't going to install that directly in your main project. The reason being is that each `node_modules/@nestjs/common` and `node_modules/@nestjs/core` have their own class references to things like `Reflector` and `ModuleRef` which Nest will eventually being doing checks of `injectedDependency instanceof Reflector` and if the wrong `Reflector` is pulled when instantiating the dependency, or during the `instanceof` check, it fails, and Nest will no longer be able to resolve the injected depdnency and the application will fail to start.

This is a side effect of [JS Realms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof#instanceof_and_multiple_realms).

As `@nestjs/throttler` already sets `@nestjs/common` and `@nestjs/core` to peerDeps, you *should* be okay with keeping it as a dependency, but as a precaution, I'd probably just set it to a `peerDependency` and be done with it. That way, if you need to make use of `@ThrottleSkip()` or the `@Throttle()` decorators you are able to without worry.

---

**Also**, *very important*, make sure you are not installing this package locally (using an `npm link` or `npm install ../package` as that will not properly respect the peer dependnecies. Either make a tarball using `npm pack` and install the tar file directly, copy the `package.json` and the `dist` to `node_modules/<my-package>`, or publish the package and install it with the usual `npm i <my-package>`

Comment: Worked ! But it also important to note that when I changed from npm link to an actual package version and installed using turbo repo, it still installed the linked package instead of the remote package, but eventually I made it installed the right package (turbo 1.8.6)